# Raspberry pi 3 - GPIO output stays at 1.8V

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I've set-up a GPIO port to output. With an external multi-meter, I've noticed that the potential stays at 1.8V in respect to the ground.

I've checked in respect with the same ground, and the 3V3 and 5V ports are actually giving the correct potential.

When I check the ports with "gpio readall", I notice that the port is set on and off. However, the potential stays at 1.8V. Does anyone has a possible solution?

Comment: does a GPIO also have to be set pull-up/down when it is being used as an output source?

Comment: [Internal Pull Down Resistor on an Output Pin?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/70000/35753) and also https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=202568#p1259458 (apparently not!)